# Not meeting quality standards with no explanation

Tags: discussion, low-quality

I am trying to post the following question and getting **this post does not meet our quality standards**. Can someone please tell me why? Can I suggest more constructive denials?

---

I have a machine with 32 cpus (NUMA) running CentOS 6.4. I would like to dedicate cpus 0-27 to my application, and leave the other 4 for everything else, including irq handling.

Is it enough to set `isolcpus=0-27` in grub.conf, or do I need to also configure irqbalance to mask `IRQBALANCE_BANNED_CPUS=0fffffff` ?

I thought I could verify this with `cat /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity` after setting that irqbalance variable and restarting, but I see affinities like this:

```
0000ff00
0000ff00
ffffffff
0000ff00
0000ff00
0000ff00
0000ff00
0000ff00
0000ff00
00ff0000
00ff0000
00ff0000
00ff0000
ffffffff
00ff0000
00ff0000
00ff0000
00ff0000
ff000000
ff000000
ff000000
```

or, if I start irqbalance in the foreground with --debug, I see this:

```
NUMA NODE NUMBER: 0
LOCAL CPU MASK: 000000ff

NUMA NODE NUMBER: 1
LOCAL CPU MASK: 0000ff00

NUMA NODE NUMBER: 2
LOCAL CPU MASK: 00ff0000

NUMA NODE NUMBER: 3
LOCAL CPU MASK: ff000000
```

both of which make me think irqbalance doesn't work properly with NUMA, etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

See here: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

It's probably your subject line, or the fact that there's too many large code blocks, making the system think you're asking us to plz send teh codes.

Comment: same thing without the code blocks. I tried a longer title and it worked, thanks.